# Is it possible to upload a string/js object without having it stored in a file? - IPFS

Tags: javascript, json, string, file, ipfs

I have been playing around with [js-ipfs](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs) API and wanted to ask if anyone knows wheather js-ipfs supports only uploading of files/folders? Is there a way to upload, for example a javascript object like:

```
{
    heading:"SomeHeading",
    content:"somecontent"
}
```

or a string like

```
"{heading:\"SomeHeading\", content:\"somecontent\"}"
```

So far I have tried:

```
const ipfs = window.IpfsApi('localhost', 5001, {protocol: 'https'});
const buffer = ipfs.Buffer;

async function uploadToIpfs() {
    let someObject = {
        heading:"SomeHeading",
        content:"someContent"
    };

    let objectString = JSON.stringify(someObject);

    let bufferedString = await buffer.from(objectString);

    await ipfs.add(bufferedString, (err, resp) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(resp);
    });
}
```

but I get 
[image]

Any help with resolving this problem or just a stright up answer of wheather it is possible to just upload a js object or string would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Im a bit late with the response but I found the answer to the problem. As @Miguel Mota said below I should change `{protocol: 'https'}` to `{protocol: 'http'}` since im on localhost. The other problem that arised after that was that I was getting a CORS error which I fixed by running this command in cmd `ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin "[\"http://localhost:9090\"]"` where `http://localhost:9090` is the http-server of my app. Also these [resources](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-api) helped me alot!

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and all you need to do is change the `protocol` to `http` since you're on localhost.

```
{protocol: 'http'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to upload arbitrary object content; therefore, you want an abstract-blob-storage. This can be done using [ipfs-blob-store](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-blob-store/).

Make sure to read the docs but to get the idea:

```
var ipfsBlobStore = require('ipfs-blob-store')

var options = {
  port: 5001,   // default value
  host: '127.0.0.1', // default value
  baseDir: '/', // default value
  flush: true  // default value
}    
var store = ipfsBlobStore(options)

var ws = store.createWriteStream({
  key: 'some/path/file.txt'
})

ws.write("{heading:\"SomeHeading\", content:\"somecontent\"}")
ws.end(function() {
  var rs = store.createReadStream({
    key: 'some/path/file.txt'
  })

  rs.pipe(process.stdout)
})
```